# Why can't we get the files we've dragged in

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

This is a electron +vue3 + vite project.
Now I can drag the folder here and get nothing
I want to get the file that I dragged in.

electron: 23.0.0
vue: 3.2.0

```js
<template>
  <div class="split-view">
    <div class="split-view-main">
      <div class="split-view-main-content">
        <div
          class="pane"
          ref="pane"
          @drop.stop.prevent="handleDrop"
          @dragover="handleDragover"
          @dragenter="handleDragover"
        >
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  import { isFolder } from '@/utils/file'

  function handleDrop(e: DragEvent) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()

    let { items } = e.dataTransfer!

    console.log('items--->', e, items)
    if (items && items[0].webkitGetAsEntry() !== null) {
      isFolder(items)
    }
  }

  function handleDragover(e: any) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'
  }
</script>
```

This is the drag event from the console:
[image: log]

Comment: Tried your example in Firefox, I am getting a drop event where `dataTransfer` contains files/folders